# Interaction effects in modeling with multicollinearity

Tags: regression, linear, model, multicollinearity, intervention-analysis

I have a large model in r like:
sales = ai+ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 +(x1*x4) + (x2*x4) + (x3*x4), where x4 is a dummy for a certain interventoin. As a result, i wanted to analyse the effect of x1,x2,x3 during intervention and without intervention. One problem i experience is multicollinearity.

I thought about makeing 2 seperate models like:
sales = ai+ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 +(x1*x4) + (x2*x4) + (x3*x4),
sales = ai+(x1*x4) + (x2*x4) + (x3*x4)

and compare their coeficient to generate a conclusion about the effect of the intervention.
However, i am not sure if this is an apprpriate way to handle this.
DO you guys spot any danger in this method or sugget other procedures to do this?

Thank you in advance?